# Multiple simultaneous processes within one thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, simultaneous

I have an app which will listen to four channels of input audio (These four channels can be from completely different sources).

My question is how to implement this efficiently.  At first I tried simply nesting the following code:

```
 try (TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) m1.getLine(info1)) {
         line.open(format1);
            line.start();
```

within each other for the four channels.  This worked, however, if one source is stopped or disappears, this will prevent all child TargetDataLines from executing.

I then realized that wanting individual control, it may be better to create a thread for each input.  (I am taking an audio buffer, then deinterleaving  to get the desired channel, then converting to a float for this array to then be processed later).  So I went about doing this and had four instances of the thread running the code.
However this seemed to make the application run a lot slower, and other processes on another thread started taking a lot longer. (notably, a process I had representing a meter for the incoming audio channel went from taking about 20ms to process up to 3100 ms to process!),

```
audioInput(String name, String audiointerface, String selectedchannel, String totalchannel ){
    threadName = name;
    interfaceName = audiointerface;
    selectedChannel = selectedchannel;
    totalChannel = totalchannel;
}

public void run(){
   synchronized (audioInputMonitor){
    System.out.println("audipInput1 Threrad is running");
    while (continuousLoop){
        while(!pauseInput){
        try {
            System.out.println("captureaudio method loading");
            captureAudio1();
            System.out.println("Finished capture method");

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(audioInput.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(audioInput.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
    while (pauseInput){
        try {
             System.out.println("t is waiting"); 
             audioInputMonitor.wait();
             System.out.println("t finished waiting");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             System.out.println("Interrupted waiting");
        }
    }
}



public void start(){
    System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
    t = new Thread (this, threadName);
    t.start();
}
```

I then created four instances of this thread.  captureAudio() is a running process which opens a targetdataline with a given format for the variables sent to audioInput at the top of this code.  This process is then on a continuous loop always feeding a stream to the buffer.

Ideally, I only want to run three threads,  my application thread, one for audio IO, and one for processing the data. Is it possible to have one thread, and in that create four instances of a class which are running on a continuous loop simultaneously?  I am struggling to see how to do this efficiently. Else was I correct to begin with and need to nest four sets of start line, one within another to keep them in the same thread.

Comment: A little hard to understand what you are trying to achive and what you have tried... Can you please use some code to explain it?

Comment: yes, sorry.  I didn't do too much code in my initial question because I didn't necessarily want pointing out where I went wrong, but more just a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: edited with the code for the threads. I effectively want to make four instances of this run within one thread.